# Confused about if $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} n + 1/(2n) = n$ a limit point?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am currently learning real analysis through the book Davidson-Donsig-2010-Real Analysis and Aplications. In Closed and Open Subsets part of the book, I'm little confused about the limit points. The definition from book is:

> A point $x$ is a limit point of a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ if there is a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $a_n \in A$ such that $x = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n$. A set $A \subset \mathbb{R}_n$ is closed if it contains all of its limit points.

For set $\{n + 1/(2n): n\in \mathbb{N}^+\}$, I can prove it is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ by proving its component is the union of open set which is still open. But $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} n + 1/(2n) = n$ is a limit point right? It seems $n\notin \{n + 1/(2n): n\in \mathbb{N}^+\}$. So is this contradict with it's closed?

Comment: $n$ cannot be used as both a dummy variable (on the left) and as a fixed quantity (on the right).

Comment: $\lim n+1/(2n)=+\infty$, not $n$! Therefore your limit does not exist in $\mathbb{R}$.